# check condition of radio button

Tags: java, winforms, radio-button

I have a radio button that turns a string into binary format in my editText field. Once the user enters a number, that number should be converted into binary. I've checked if the binary radio button is pressed. The first time the user enters a value it works great and is converted to binary.
But once they enter a different number it stays in decimal form.

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example.  Basically, it sounds like you need an `ActionListener` on the field and/or a "Convert" button

Comment: You need some way to allow the method to execute.  Either you need to select the "binary" button again or have some other means to trigger the method, such as an `ActionListener` on the field (so the user can press the `enter` key) or a "calcaulte" button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace the radio button in a real button and register the `actionListener`:

```
    rb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           if(rb.getChecked())
           {
                String toBinray=this.editText.getText().toString();
                String bin=Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.valueOf(toBinray));
                this.displayText.setText(bin);
           }
           else
           {
                // Convert the binary value to integer
           }
        }
    });
```

if you must stay with radio button register it's `actionListener`, but you also must check the input is in binary form if the radio is checked.

Comment: @CalvinJones ok, so add the actionListener in the answer to the radioButton, but you must also make sure the user input is in the right form... if you are in binary format you can only accept '0' or '1'

Comment: @CalvinJones i'll try to figure it out, but i'm not sure i'll make it.